# socket C client specific number

Tags: c, sockets

I have a server code  in C that accepts 5 clients. Also, have a separate file client.c However, If I want for each client a specific integer number(enter by user) that not allow him to connect to the server again how can i do that 
Is there a specific data structure or way to send that number to the server.

Server and Client programs should work on same and different machines.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please make your question clear.

Are all your clients running on the same machine?

If all clients are running on different machines then probably you can keep a track of their IP addresses and then you can allow each client to connect once.

Comment: sorry about that..Server and Client programs should work on same and different machines.

Comment: Client is a process or a running program. It connects with the server as a new process every time. Once you connect a client with the server and then disconnect then that client is dead and it can never be alive again. You start a new client process every time. I think I understood your question rite.